# Field authenticationManager LoginController required a bean of typeAuthenticationManager' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Getting this error when trying to set up my SecurityConfigurer with spring security.

```
APPLICATION FAILED TO START

Description:

Field authenticationManager in com.springvuegradle.Controller.LoginController required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
        - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager' in your configuration.
```

I Have overrided the authenticationManagerBean as suggested by other answers, however this has not helped. Any advice welcome. My SecurityConfigurer class is below.

```
package com.springvuegradle.Security;

import com.springvuegradle.Services.MyUserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.NoOpPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

public class SecurityConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private MyUserDetailsService myUserDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(myUserDetailsService);
    }

    /***
     * Requires authentication for all endpoints except the /authenticate endpoint.
     */
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/authenticate").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        //TODO change this to actually hash the password
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }
}
```

LoginController

```
@RestController
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code, it seems you are trying to autowire SecurityConfigurer in LoginController. But in spring security, there is no need to autowire the configurer class. Also, as mentioned by you, overriding the authenticationManagerBean will only provide you a bean of AuthenticationManager type, not the SecurityConfigurer type.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. I believe I am only trying to autowire a bean of AuthenticationManager in my LoginController. I've added the relevant code to my original post.

Comment: It seems you forgot to add @EnableWebSecurity annotation on the SecurityConfigurer class.

Comment: Even with adding the Configuration and @EnableWebSecurity annotations the error still remains. Do you think it could be an issue with the project configuration?

Comment: It shouldn't be the case after applying the @EnableWebSecurity annotation. I tried the same piece of code and it has worked for me. It will be able to find the AuthenticationManager bean and autowiring it is totally possible.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue,I discovered that I forgot to add @Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity to my SecurityConfig file.

```
 @Configuration @EnableWebSecurity
 public class SecurityConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {}
```

This should fix your issue.It will autowire the AuthenticationManager bean

Also this NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance(); is deprecated in spring 2.5.5 use this instead

```
   //deprecated in spring boot 2.5.5
   @Bean
   public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
    return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
   }
   //Use this below
   @Bean
  PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder() {
     return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
  }
```